# With SwiftData, I'm adding a local notification based on a date in a obj . Using binding to update the obj, how do it update the local notification?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift-data

The binding is directly updating the item object. Is there a callback or something I can use to update notification ?

```
struct EditInventoryItemFormView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query var locations: [Location]
    @State var viewModel: EditInventoryItemViewModel

    
    var body: some View {
        Form{
            TextField("Name", text:  $viewModel.item.name)
            Toggle("Has Expiration Date", isOn: $viewModel.item.hasExpriationDate)
            if viewModel.item.hasExpriationDate{
                DatePicker("Expiration Date", selection: $viewModel.item.expirationDate, displayedComponents: [.date])
                    .padding()
            }
            TextField("Qty", value: $viewModel.item.qty, format: .number)
                .padding()
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
        
            Picker("Location", selection: $viewModel.item.location) {
                ForEach(Array(locations), id: \.self) { loc in
                    Text(loc.name)
                        .tag(loc as? Location)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to know when a object has been updated in swift data.

Comment: It’s not easy to understand this question, what do you mean with local notification in this context and what is the binding you mention? Is it viewModel.item?

Comment: A post notification that is not remote. I am binding a model that has an expiration date. I need to know when this is updated.

Comment: You will need some code, possibly a `didSet` on the `item.expirationDate` property or an `onChange` listener in your view (Have the `DatePicker` use a local `@State` property and then update your notification and the model property in the `onChange` handler.